# I can't install MariaDB in Homestead v9

Tags: laravel, vagrant, mariadb, homestead

Lastly i tried to pull and install the Homestead environment of one of my Laravel project. Everything is working fine except i can't install MariaDB in the Vagrant box. I used to add `mariadb: true` in the `homestead.yaml` file that comes with Homestead, but nothing happens now. I use Laravel 5.8 / Homestead v9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in this release https://github.com/laravel/homestead/releases/tag/v9.0.0,

> New “Feature” syntax to install optional services or tools such as Golang, MariaDB, etc.

In order to install MariaDB or any other external services, you now need to add a `features` setting in your `homestead.yaml`:

```
features:
    - mariadb: true
```

The Laravel documentation has also been updated accordingly: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead#installing-optional-features

This problem is insidious since it only happens when you reinstall your Vagrant box, not when you update Homestead (because the services you need are already installed when you update).